# Why won't my input work?

Tags: php, javascript, post

When I press a button, all my values is being ​​posted, but I only want the selected to be posted to the same page

I have a dynamic table which contains 4 values:

- OrderID
- member id
- Title
- Checked

The first three values ​​are text while the last value is a button that you can press that you can look at the code.

When I choose to press one button for the selected row, I gett all OrderID for ALL rows instead of only the selected row.

Why is this happening?

```
foreach($menuextra_result as $key){
                ?>
<form action="">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3" id="textBox" >#<?= $key['order_id']; ?></div>
            <div class="span3"><?= $key['member_id']; ?></div>
            <div class="span4"><?= $key['title']; ?></div>


            <?php 
            $checked = isset($key['checked'])?($key['checked']) :"";
            ?>
            <?php if($checked)
            { 
            ?>
            <div class="span2" ><?= date('d-m-y H:i:s', $checked) ?></div>
            <?php 
            } 
            else 
            {
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" id="order_id" name="order_id" value="<?= $key['order_id']; ?>"></input>
            <input class="span2" type="submit" value="Ja">
            <?php 
            }
            ?>         
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div><!-- / white-box -->
</form>
```

```
$(function(){
    $('#save').click(function () 
    {
        var mysave = $('#textBox').html();

    });
});
```

Comment: your form close-tag is outside the foreach area. so the form isnt closed after each row.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you use id multiple times in an array...

Comment: this is not a good title.

Comment: @steven: Arhh thanx steven :D

Comment: Where is the `#save` button? I don't see it in the HTML code. Also, what is that jQuery for? You don't say anything.

Answer (score 2):

Can it be that you are setting the same ID to every row?

```
id="textBox"
```

Comment: Are you answering or questioning?

Comment: This looked plausible...but apparently `.html()` only returns the HTML for the first element, so one div's value (and no others) should always appear in `mysave`.  Also, it wouldn't affect the form submission; what the server sees is based on the name, not the ID, and names are allowed to not be unique.